# "throw out/away" vs. "toss (out)" vs. "pitch (out/away)" for "dispose of; discard; get rid of as worthless or useless" in AmEng

Tags: american-english, word-usage, formality, register, dialects

What's the difference between "throw out/away," "toss out," and "pitch (out/away)" to mean, "get rid of as worthless or unnecessary"? Can these be used just about interchangeably?

THROW AWAY

> Also, *throw out* or *toss out*. Dispose of, discard, as in *This coat is too good to throw away*, or *Did you throw out the rest of the milk?* or *She tossed out all his old letters*. [First half of 1500s]
>
> [The American Heritage® Dictionary of Idioms by Christine Ammer](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Throw+away)

TOSS/TOSS OUT

> **toss**
>
> To get rid of :  throw away
>
> [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/toss)
>
> **toss out**
>
> (*US*) To put (something that is no longer useful or wanted) in a trash can, garbage can, etc. :  to throw (something) out *It's time to toss out those bananas.* *Did you toss the newspapers out already?*
>
> [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/toss%20out)

PITCH, PITCH OUT, and PITCH AWAY

> **pitch**
>
> [+ object] : to throw or toss (something)
>
> *Passersby on the street pitched coins into her open guitar case as she played.*
>
> *They were pitching horseshoes.*
>
> *She pitched the empty box into the garbage.*
>
> [Merriam-Webster Learners Dictionary](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/pitch)
>
> To discard by throwing: *pitched my worn-out sneakers*.
>
> [The American Heritage® Dictionary](http://thefreedictionary.com/pitch)
>
> To put aside or discard by or as if by throwing *pitched the trash into the bin*
>
> [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pitch)
>
> **pitch something out**
>
> To throw something away; to discard something. *This cottage cheese is so old, I'm going to pitch it out*. *They pitched out the bad food*.
>
> [McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pitch+out)
>
> **pitch something away**
>
> To toss or throw something away. *He pitched the broken stick away, and looked around for something stronger*. *He pitched away the stick*.
>
> [McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pitch+away)

Comment: Number of [questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A65205+AE) asked about AE (American English): 50. [Questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A65205+AmEng) asked about AmEng: 45 Total questions asked about American English: 95 I think we should be coming to you for advice.

Comment: @Mari-LouA it's a good idea, Mari-Lou. I'll have to take it under advisement. ;-)

Comment: As a life-long US resident, I would say that "throw away" and "throw out" are interchangeable.  "Toss out" might be a bit less likely to be used in the figurative sense; i.e., I would use it only in the literal sense of throwing something out a window (or throwing a person out through the door).  If I heard "pitch away" or "pitch out" in a non-sports context, I might say "Huh?"  ("Pitch" in general, and "pitch out" in particular, have meanings that are specific to American baseball.)  YMMV

Comment: I am 58 years old. Originally from the Mid-West. I was often told to "pitch" things, especially rotten food and other things that were not needed anymore, since I was a child. I came to this link because some of the younger workers at the company I work for in California were unfamiliar with the usage and confused when it was used by a vendor they were talking to in the Mid-West, and I was trying to learn if it was regional usage...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Speaking for myself, the terms have basically the same meaning. However "Toss out" is a bit wordy for casual conversation. You can simply say "toss". In that context others should understand you intend to dispose of the item. The word "pitch" tends to put an emphasis on the emotional component of the act of disposing of the item.

Toss is used when you simply wish to be rid of the item. Pitch tends to show more determination. As if you want to damage the item in the process of getting rid of it.

Comment: Yeah, "toss" is dismissive, while "pitch" usually implies some consideration.  (And I can't say that I've ever heard "pitch away".)

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard someone say 'pitch' in reference to putting something in the garbage.  Most common would be "throw" "toss" or "chuck," eg "I chucked it out" or "Throw it in the trash." Tossing has the implication of a lighter touch, like an underhanded throw.